# Sidekiq running multiple jobs in a single heroku dyno?

Tags: multithreading, heroku, concurrency, sidekiq

I have noticed that on some of my sidekiq workers, they appear to be running multiple processes (Working multiple jobs concurrently) in a single dyno (The logs would suggest this).

How many processes could be/are running separate jobs within a single dyno concurrently without using swarming (The enterprise feature)?

I have everything set up to defaults without using swarms, so each sidekiq worker is using 25 threads. What exactly all these threads are used for, however, I have no idea. Can anyone help me understand how this translates into concurrent workers working jobs inside a single Heroku dyno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing a single Sidekiq process with 25 threads running jobs concurrently.  Each thread will execute a job so you can have up to 25 jobs running at once.

Without swarm, you can only run one process per dyno.

You can run multiple processes in a dyno using swarm but how many depends on the memory requirements of your app and how many cores in the dyno.

This will get you 100 worker threads: 4*25.

```
SIDEKIQ_COUNT=4 bundle exec sidekiqswarm -e production -c 25
```

Comment: Just to clarify the impact of adding swarms. Total concurrent job processing would be: swarm size (# processes) * threads/process = total jobs that could be simultaneously processed? In my case this might be as high as 8 cores (one process each) * 25 threads per process = 200 jobs concurrently processed per dyno?

Comment: Correct.  Make sure you have enough memory in your dyno to support 8 processes.  You generally want ~1GB each if you are going to use the default concurrency of 25.